# Copy price categories to custom field

Tags: custom-field, mysql

I have just made a big mistake today using a plugin to convert my 1000+ price custom fields into child categories under Price.  I didn't know the custom fields will be deleted after the conversion.

The prices are still attach to their respective posts and I'll really appreciate it if somebody can help me with sql query to copy the values back to the price custom field.

this is my function.php including your code

```
<?php
//get all categories ID's in to array
$args = array( 'child_of'  =>3678);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
$cat_array = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat_array[] = $category->term_id;
  }

$Query_args = array(
    'category__in' =>$cat_array );
$new_query = new WP_Query();
$new_query->query($Query_args);
if ($new_query->have_posts()){
    while ($new_query->have_posts()){
        $new_query->the_post();
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
            if (in_array($category->cat_ID,$cat_array){
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'price', $category->cat_name);
            }
        }
    }
}


/*************************************************************
* Do not modify unless you know what you're doing, SERIOUSLY!
*************************************************************/

/* Admin framework version 2.0 by Zeljan Topic */

// Theme variables
require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/library/functions/theme_variables.php');

//** ADMINISTRATION FILES **//

// Theme admin functions
require_once ($functions_path . 'admin_functions.php');

// Theme admin options
require_once ($functions_path . 'admin_options.php');

// Theme admin Settings
require_once ($functions_path . 'admin_settings.php');



//** FRONT-END FILES **//

// Widgets
require_once ($functions_path . 'widgets_functions.php');

// Comments
require_once ($functions_path . 'comments_functions.php');

// Yoast's plugins
require_once ($functions_path . 'yoast-breadcrumbs.php');

require_once ($functions_path . 'yoast-posts.php');

//require_once ($functions_path . 'yoast-canonical.php');

require_once ($functions_path . 'yoast-breadcrumbs.php');

/////////shopping cart new function files
require($functions_path . "general_functions.php");
require($functions_path . "cart.php");
require($functions_path . "product.php");
require($functions_path . "custom.php");
require(TEMPLATEPATH . "/product_menu.php");
// Custom
require_once ($functions_path . 'custom_functions.php');

///message - language file
require(TEMPLATEPATH . "/message.php");
if('themes.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])  && $_REQUEST['page']=='') 
{
    if($_REQUEST['dummy']=='del')
    {
        delete_dummy_data();    
        echo THEME_DUMMY_DELETE_MESSAGE;
    }
    $post_counts = $wpdb->get_var("select count(post_id) from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key='pt_dummy_content'");
    if(($_REQUEST['template']=='' && $post_counts>0 && $_REQUEST['page']=='') || $_REQUEST['activated']=='true')
    {
        echo THEME_ACTIVE_MESSAGE;
    }
    if($_REQUEST['activated'])
    {
        require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/auto_install.php');
    }
}

function delete_dummy_data()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $productArray = array();
    $pids_sql = "select p.ID from $wpdb->posts p join $wpdb->postmeta pm on pm.post_id=p.ID where meta_key='pt_dummy_content' and meta_value=1";
    $pids_info = $wpdb->get_results($pids_sql);
    foreach($pids_info as $pids_info_obj)
    {
        wp_delete_post($pids_info_obj->ID);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste this code in you theme's function.php file

```
//get all categorie ID's in to array
$args = array( 'child_of'  => 3678); // Parent category ID
$categories = get_categories( $args );
$cat_array = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat_array[] = $category->term_id;
  }

$Query_args = array(
    'category__in' => $cat_array,
    'post_type' => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME'
);
$new_query = new WP_Query();
$new_query->query($Query_args);
if ($new_query->have_posts()){
    while ($new_query->have_posts()){
        $new_query->the_post();
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
            if (in_array($category->cat_ID,$cat_array)){
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'price', $category->cat_name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

replace "Parent category ID" with price category ID and then save that file
after that remove this code and save again.

Comment: Thanks for that Bainternet but I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 18 .... I had placed the code below <?php and replaced the parent category with price id...I've been trying for the past hour but I just couldn't find it..

Comment: paste the code that you are using?

Comment: Hi Bainternet,  I've posted the code above...

Comment: i see its missing a frikin ")" at the end of  if (in_array($category->cat_ID,$cat_array) . I updated the code in the answer so just copy it and replace with the one in your functions.php

Comment: thank you, i can't believe i didn't see that...now, i have removed the code after saving it and notice that my price custom fields are still empty...am i suppose to give it a little bit more of time for everthing to be process?

Comment: after saving it was suppose to run and update your custom fields with the category names. if you can't see it being updated in your post then i guess there is something wrong with the query, are you using a custom post type?

Comment: my product_detail.php calls the price like this..  <p><strong>Price: <span class="price"> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $single = true); ?> </span></strong></p> ...

Comment: if you are using custom post type the you should have mentioned it, anyway add 'post_type' => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME' to the $Query_args array

Comment: thank you very much for your help....everything is back to normal now

Comment: glad it worked out ok